# How to make a div resizable for users?

Tags: javascript, html, resize

What is the simplest way to offer a *resize div* method for users, such as the StackOverflow text box. Can this be done via HTML only or is JavaScript required?
[image]

Comment: Is the thick bottom handle also a requirement, or just being able to resize the div somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="resize:vertical;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

Did you mean this?

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO FIDDLE (2 and 3)](http://jsfiddle.net/EbUN4/)**

1. If you want it to look and behave exactly like the textarea in SO, then you definitely need JavaScript. **[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819328/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-textarea-by-dragging-mouse)**.
2. If you just want a simple realizable div to *display* text, this should be sufficient:

HTML

```
<div class="display-info">Resizeable div</div>
```

CSS

```
.display-info {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow:auto; 
    width: 250px; 
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

3. If you want a textarea that allows users to type something in it (For eg: a form):

HTML

```
<textarea name="test" id="test" cols="30" rows="10">Text area</textarea>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    resize: vertical; /* can on be resized vertically*/
}
```